# Azure Function (Python 3.10, v2) cannot be found in the Logic App (Consumption) workflow designer

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

An http-triggered Azure Function developed using programming model v2 in Python 3.10 cannot be found in the Logic App (Consumption) workflow designer.

The region, subscription, and resource group for both Logic App and Function App are the same.

The function is running and works well. The only problem is that the logic app built-in module the function cannot be found as an action.

The Azure Function was developed following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators).

The `local.settings.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "my_azure_storage_account_connecting_string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

The previous http-triggered function was created in Python 3.7 using programming model v1. This function can be easily triggered from Logic App workflow (in the new logic app it can be found). The previous function and  current function I am trying to develop are used in a totally different Logic Apps. I am doing all this because Microsoft recommend to update functions with a new programming mode.

I have checked similar old issues, however I haven't foudn any proper solution for Python v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my results:

When you call a V2 Model Function from Consumption plan of Logic apps it will not show you the functions as below:

[image]

But, When you create a logic app with Standard Plan then you will be able to see and trigger the function as below:

[image]

Now after creating when i called Logic apps below is my output:

[image]

So, to call functions v2 model from Logic apps you need to created Logic apps in Standard Plan.

Comment: Thanks, it shows in this case, though the payment is fixed, thus I used HTTP request with GET method instead Azure Functions in the consumption tier Logic Apps.